# How can I add a minimum of days based on hour in datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

My code javascript like this :

```
$(function () {    
  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().startOf('day')
  }).on('dp.change', function(e){
    if( e.date && e.date.isSame(moment(), 'd') ){
      var min = moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm');
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(min);
    } else {
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }
  });

  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().startOf('minute').add(300, 'm'),
  });
});
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/tyvetr5h/

My problem :

For example now on 16 August at 9 pm. As it appears that the date displayed is 17 August at 2 am. But my code is August 16 at 2 am

How can I solve it?

I try to update the day like this :

```
minDate: moment().startOf('day').add(300, 'm')
```

But it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the 300 minutes to the DP `mindate` when instantiating too. Since this "moment" is the current time and date, that is relevant to add it.

I'm not the same timezone as you, so I had to add more than 300 minutes to make it fall on tomorrow... But here is your [**updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/33fg90kh/3/). I removed all [`.startOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), which I think is irrelevant in what you try to achieve.

**EDIT**
I found the trick.

The thing is that you change the moment value... so when it is time to compare the dates, better do it in "Unix format", which is in milliseconds from january 1st 1970...

That long integer doesn't care about the day change. So it is easier (and error proof) to compare if the time is 300 minutes from now.

```
$(function () {

  console.clear();

  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(300, 'm').startOf("day")
  })
    .val(moment().add(300, 'm').format("DD-MM-YYYY"))   // To set correct "valid" date from start

    .on('dp.change', function(e){
    var now = moment().format("X");
    //console.log(e.date.format("X"));
    //console.log(now);

    // Comparing selected date (moment object) in milliseconds
    if(e.date.format("X")+(300*60*1000) > now ){
      console.log("above 5 hours, unlocking time.");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }else{
      console.log("below 5 hours, locking time (and probably resetting the value to min...)");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
    }

  });

  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(300, 'm'),
  });
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PKQwJa?editors=1011)

Comment: Timepicker can only be selected at least 5 hours from now. So user can not decrement hours. Your code, the user can still decrement hours

Comment: I don't get what you mean... In the Fiddle I posted, User just can't select a date/time below the setted minimum.

Comment: If first load then choose timepicker, it works. user can not decrement hours. But if user select datepicker then select timepicker, it can decrement hours

Comment: User can decrement hour if the date above isn't today... If user decremented time, he just cant select today... So there is no problem.

Comment: I mean like this. If now is 3 am. Then user can only choose above 5 hours from now. So the user can only select over at 8 am. User can not decrement the timepicker to 7 am or below 8 am.

Comment: No he can't! But he can select 7am on the next day. If he does, he just can't come back to re-select today because it is below the min date. Have a close look at the date... And notice it doesn't come back to today.

Comment: You try to click on the input text datepicker first. Then you click timepicker and decrement hour, it can. I have tried your jsfiddle. I try today

Comment: Ho... Just a click without selecting another date... Ok I see.

Comment: Okay. It works. But it looks like there are still bugs. For example this time is 3 am. Datepicker will auto input: 2017-08-18 and timepicker: 8 am. If I change the datepicker to 2017-08-19 and timepicker: 6 am. Then I changed the datepicker to the date 2017-08-18. The result will be: datepicker 2017-08-18, timepicker 6 am. User can input it. The user should only be able to input it 5 hours from now. So if the case is like that, the user can still input it

Comment: Okay. I will also try to find a solution