# How can I clear input text on datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Demo and full code like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/yfjvd200/

I want the datepicker and timepicker not filled when loaded the first time. I want the datepicker or timepicker to filled when the user clicks on the input text of each. Eg user click on timepicker text input then time will be filled

I try use this :

```
  $('#datepicker').val("");
  $('#timepicker').val("");
```

But it does not work

How can I do it?

Comment: You have to write these two lines `$('#datepicker').val("");$('#timepicker').val("");` at the end of the function.

Comment: The datepicker automatically fills the input field with the date ??

Comment: If it does show reffer to documentation there must be some options

Comment: @ravisachaniya, It works.  But when I click input text datepicker first, time is not filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right trick!

```
$('#datepicker').val("");
$('#timepicker').val("");
```

But you are not doing it at the right moment. Place that AFTER the pickers have been instanciated.

To fill the time on focus, add this `.on()` to timepicker:

```
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
  minDate: moment().add(300, 'm'),
})
  .on('focus', function(e){
  if( $(this).val() == "" ){
    $(this).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/yfjvd200/8/)

Comment: It works.  But when I click input text timepicker first, time is not filled

Comment: So need to add dp.change    on the timepicker too?

Comment: It looks like my project is still not working. If opening the first time, then I select date is tomorrow then when I select time, it can not be decrement hour. If i try your fiddle, it works. Seems there is a global setting in my project that affects this. Or maybe because of the different versions of the plugin used. So seems in `focus` I need to add condition again like this :  `if( $(this).val() == "" ){ if(datepicker is today)
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
    else $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
}`. How do you think?

Comment: It solved. I try like this : `if($(this).val() == "") {
    var datepickerSelected = $('#datepicker').val();
    var today = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    if(datepickerSelected == today)
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
    else
        $('#timepicker').val(moment().add(300, 'm').format("HH:mm"))
}`

Comment: I also reworked it... [Have a look](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/44b6qrvu/), maybe it could help ;)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have tried your fiddle. If the text input of the timepicker is clicked, the current time does not automatically appear in the input text of the timepicker. It should be automatically displayed, although not yet selected

Comment: It seems there are still shortcomings. Now in my city at 22.30 PM. If I click on the input text in the datepicker, it does not automatically appear. The date only automatically appears if the time is smaller at 19.00 Pm. Should be if I click on input text of datepicker  at any hour, the date automatic appear

Comment: I don't see why the date would not be filled in the input... After 19H00, the date to auto appear should be the next day's date, that's the only difference. It is actually 11H46 am here... I will look at this evening.

Comment: Okay. The problem here : if  selected datepicker != today then the textbox of the datepicker does not automatically appear

Comment: okay... I found a way to reproduce that issue... And you're right... Hold on.

Comment: Okay... That is fixed. See the added `.on("dp.show", ...` for `#datepicker` in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/t0z3td1u/). --- That was a *strange* issue which I don't really understand...

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems your code is still not perfect. `minTime` is taken from the first time the fiddle executed. Should it be taken when the timepicker is clicked. For example I run your jsfidde at 15.00. After 5 minutes, I choose timepicker, the result is fixed at 20.00. Should be at 20:05

Comment: I make the new question. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736713/how-can-i-get-current-time-when-the-timepicker-clicked

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write these lines to end of your function :

```
$('#datepicker').val("");
$('#timepicker').val("");
```

You can use this code  :

```
$(function () {
  console.clear();

  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(300, 'm').startOf("day")
  })
    .val(moment().add(300, 'm').format("DD-MM-YYYY"))   // To set correct "valid" date from start

    .on('dp.change', function(e){
    var now = moment().format("X");
    //console.log(e.date.format("X"));
    //console.log(now);

    // Comparing selected date (moment object) in milliseconds
    if(e.date.format("X")+(300*60*1000) > now ){
      console.log("above 5 hours, unlocking time.");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }else{
      console.log("below 5 hours, locking time (and probably resetting the value to min...)");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
    }

  });

  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(300, 'm'),
  });

  $('#datepicker').val("");
  $('#timepicker').val("");
});
```

Comment: It works. But when I click input text datepicker first, time is not filled

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/yfjvd200/9/. I have commented some lines

```
$(function () {
  //$('#datepicker').val("");
  //$('#timepicker').val("");
  console.clear();

  $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment().add(300, 'm').startOf("day")
  })
    //.val(moment().add(300, 'm').format("DD-MM-YYYY"))   // To set correct "valid" date from start

    .on('dp.change', function(e){
    var now = moment().format("X");
    //console.log(e.date.format("X"));
    //console.log(now);

    // Comparing selected date (moment object) in milliseconds
    if(e.date.format("X")+(300*60*1000) > now ){
      console.log("above 5 hours, unlocking time.");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }else{
      console.log("below 5 hours, locking time (and probably resetting the value to min...)");
      $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));
    }

  });

  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    //minDate: moment().add(300, 'm'),
  }).on('dp.change', function(e){ $('#timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().add(300, 'm'));});
});
```

Comment: That doesn't only empty the fields, but also changes the functionality.

Comment: By functionality, I meant the addition of 300 minutes to the min date. That is needed in OP code. I'm sure of this because this was the topic of [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717230/how-can-i-add-a-minimum-of-days-based-on-hour-in-datetimepicker/45717963?noredirect=1#comment78537372_45717963).