# How can I get the current time when the timepicker is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, eonasdan-datetimepicker

My code looks like this:

```
  // TIME
  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: minTime,
  })

    .on('dp.show', function(e){
    console.log(selectedDate);
    if($(this).val()==""){
      $(this).val(minTime.format("HH:mm"));
    }

    // If the date is not selected yet, Nothing to do... Onload min date applies
    if( typeof(selectedDate) == "undefined" ){
      console.log("Date undefined");

      // If a date is selected, check if it's the same date as the min date
    }else if( selectedDate == minDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")){
      console.log("Date defined - SAME");
      $(this).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minTime);

      // If the date is different from the min date
    }else{
      console.log("Date defined - Different");
      $(this).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
    }
  })
    .val("");
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/t0z3td1u/4/

It seems my code is still not perfect. `minTime` is taken from the first time the fiddle executed. 
It should be taken when the timepicker is clicked. For example I run your jsfidde at 15.00. After 5 minutes, I choose timepicker, the result is fixed at 20.00. Should be at 20:05.

How can I do it so that I can get the current time when the timepicker is clicked?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or at least working snippet

Answer (score 2):

Note: This question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789881/how-can-i-clear-input-text-on-datetimepicker/45789941?noredirect=1#comment82433769_45789941) from the OP and the accepted solution is in [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/t0z3td1u/).

As [Pedram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540183/pedram) correctly stated, you just have to get the current time when the time picker opens... And use this better value for the input.

```
// TIME
$('#timepicker').datetimepicker({
  minDate: minTime,
})

  .on('dp.show', function(e){
  console.log(selectedDate);
  if($(this).val()==""){
    minTime = moment().add(offset, 'm');  // Just get the current time here!
    $(this).val(minTime.format("HH:mm"));
  }

 // ... (Rest is unchanged)
```

**Now**, you will say that the minimum time is still unchanged in the dropdown... So a user could use the arrow down to select 20.00 instead of 20.05.

Sadly... Once a `dateTimePicker` is instantiated, there is no way to change the options like `minTime`. That is an [issue opened since may 2014 on GitHub](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/126).

I guess you'll have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

> `minTime` is taken from the first time the fiddle executed. Should it
>   be taken when the `timepicker` is clicked

So simply update the time when you change day:

```
.on('dp.change dp.update', function(e){
    var now = new Date();
    var formatted = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
    $('#timepicker').val(formatted);
})
```

You can get current time with `new Date()` or get event date with `e.date`

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0z3td1u/5/)</kbd>

If you want update it on click, use this function for `#timepicker`

Answer (score 0):

Onclick event you should get time from `new Date()` and use it